# How to draw rectangle in detection part using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, keras

I created a model which is classifying `normal_car` vs. `cop_car`.

If I pass images to `model` it gives a proper output.

But when the image is having lots of objects, how to draw a rectangle on
both of these (label: `normal_Car`, `police_Car`)?

I can draw a rectangle in the image on every object (but without using a model).

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

When you find an object in an image, OpenCV gives you its position. You would crop it and via pretrained model predict.

1. You can load H5 file model or freezed etc.

   For example:

   ```
   model = load_model("modelname.h5")
   ```
2. Find objects in images and extract object position *(x,y,w,h)*

   ```
   (_, Contours ,_) = cv2.findContours(Image,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
   for area in Contours:
       (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(area)
       ObjROI = Image[y : y+h, x : x+w]
       p = model.predict(cv2.resize(ObjROI, (<size of CNN input>)))
   ```

Now you have accuracy of object that you find and its position, draw rectangle and put it text.

Comment: thanks Amin , i think this will help me , can you please tell me , where do i enter the `path` of the image ,

Comment: `TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'image'`i got this error , and what does `Image ` mean here ??

Comment: `Image` is your input frame or input image you read it at first that you must change type to float (befor the loop). `Image = np.array(Image, dtype = 'float32') / 255.0` if your output is in range 0~1.